# How to copy recent files from current direction?[Bash]

Tags: bash

How can I copy the 2 most recent updated files from a directory? I'v searched for a while now and I can't seem to find it..

If anyone can help me I would really appreciate that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this

```
rsync `ls -tp | grep -v / | head -n 2` <destination> <options>
```

Just make changes in appropriate places and it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in `ls -rt | tail -n2` ; do cp $i <dest> ; done
```

`ls -rt` sorts the files in reverse order on the basis of modification time.